# Number of inversions in permutation if subarray of permutation is reversed?

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I have `permutation(P)` of numbers `1` to `N (<=10^5)` . Suppose I can reverse the subarray of permutation . I have to find the `summation(X*Y)` where `x` is number of forms that `P` can take by reversing any subarray of `P` and `y` is total inversions of such forms .

eg

```
if N =2 ; and given permutation = 2 1

Then summation(X*Y) = 

if i reverse subarray(1,1) = permutation = 2 1 inversion =1

if i reverse subarray(2,2) = permutation = 2 1 inversions =1 


if i reverse subarray(1,2) = permutation = 1 2 inversion =0 

summation (x*y) = 2*1 + 1*0 = 2
```

My approach is to select each `n*(n+1)/2` subarray and reverse it , calculate the inversions in it and do summation , `Complexity= O(n(n+1)/2*nlogn)=O(n^3logn)`

Is there any `O(nlogn)` approach ?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr: modify the standard binary-indexed tree algorithm for computing inversions.

In pseudocode, the standard algorithm is

```
# permutation is p[1..n]
inversions <- 0
let a[1..n] be a zeroed BIT
for i from 1 to n
    inversions <- inversions + sum(a[p[i]+1..n])  # sum is O(log n)-time via BIT
    a[p[i]] <- 1
end for
```

Instead of setting the BIT entry for an element to `1`, we set it to `i`, the number of left endpoints for intervals that could include that element. Then we multiply the sum by the number of right endpoints for intervals that could include the current element -- this is the number of intervals that would invert the pair.

```
# permutation is p[1..n]
inversions <- 0
let a[1..n] be a zeroed BIT
let b[1..n] be a zeroed BIT
for i from 1 to n
    inversions <- (inversions
        +                               sum(b[1..p[i]-1])*(n+1-i)   # inversions created by reversal
        + sum(a[p[i]+1..n])*(n+1)*n/2 - sum(b[p[i]+1..n])*(n+1-i))  # inversions not destroyed by reversal
    a[p[i]] <- 1
    b[p[i]] <- i
end for
```

Comment: Above algorithm gives another result for above input of 2 , 1 . It gives 5 while answer is 2

Comment: I think problem stated reduces to summing inversions of all permutations derived from original permutation by reversing all subarray , while your inversions exceed the above bounds . Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: please can you add little more explanation for using two BIT